# How to recur over extensible records?

Tags: recursion, elm

I am a relative beginner in Elm. I learned how to recur over records, and to create extensible records. My target application has tree-shaped data, that is to be rendered in several tree views.

In order for Elm to allow recursive models, one needs

- a Union type for the children field,
- a Maybe in that type definition, and
- the lazy anonymous function construct if Json decoding is needed.

So far so good, but I cannot combine recursion with extension. Here below is a minimized version of how far I got. This program is capable of rendering either one of the two example types (Folder and Note), but **not both**. (see lines commented with `-- NOTE` and `-- FOLDER`).

The problem is with the `kids` function. Elm doesn't allow it to produce two different output types. I am stuck with either duplicating the code, or do without record extensions. Both seems like show-stoppers.

- Is there a way to get this working with both, **extension and recursion**, and without code duplication?

[Run on Ellie](https://ellie-app.com/t59qfCZy9ha1)

```
module Main exposing (main)
import Html exposing (..)
import Maybe

-- MAIN

main = Html.beginnerProgram
  { model         = init
  , update        = update
  , view          = view
  }

-- MODEL

type alias Model =
  { folder  : Folder
  , note    : Note
  }

type alias Node a =
  { a | name     : String
      , children : Children a
  }

type alias Folder =
  { name     : String
  , children : ChildFolders
  }

type alias Note =
  { name     : String
  , children : ChildNotes
  }

type Children a   = Children a   (Maybe (List (Node a)))
type ChildFolders = ChildFolders (Maybe (List Folder))
type ChildNotes   = ChildNotes   (Maybe (List Note))

-- INIT

init : Model
init = Model
        (Folder "Parent F" someFolders)
        (Note   "Parent N" (ChildNotes Nothing))

someFolders : ChildFolders
someFolders = ChildFolders
  ( Just
    ( [ Folder "Child F1" (ChildFolders Nothing)
      , Folder "Child F2" (ChildFolders Nothing)
      , Folder "Child F3" (ChildFolders Nothing)
      ]
    )
  )

-- UPDATE

type Msg = NoOp

update : Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
  case msg of
    NoOp -> model

-- VIEW

view : Model -> Html msg
view model =
  div []
  [ viewBranch model.folder    -- FOLDER
  -- , viewBranch model.note   -- NOTE
  ]

-- viewBranch : (?) -> Html msg
viewBranch node =
  uli
  ( text node.name
    ::  ( node
          |> kids
          |> List.map viewBranch
        )
  )

uli : List (Html msg) -> Html msg
uli items = ul [] [ li [] items ]

-- kids : (?) -> (?)
kids { children } =
  case children of
    (ChildFolders data) -> Maybe.withDefault [] data      -- FOLDER
    -- (ChildNotes   data) -> Maybe.withDefault [] data   -- NOTE
```

Comment: @pzp: Thanks, that is a working solution, indeed. But unfortunately the extensible records with their easy to access properties are gone. If I replace `type Folder = F String ` with something like `type Folder =  F {field1 : String, field2 : String, ..., fieldN : String}`, then it becomes very messy. It relies on pattern matching, and if I understand right, then each time a field is added, all getters/setters need to be rewritten.

Comment: @pzp's suggestion of a rose tree is pretty standard for this type of scenario. It has the benefit of separating the contents of each node from the recursive data structure. Extensible records are not going to work in the way you've defined `Node a` because the child `List (Node a)` will not type check against the other child types you've defined.

Comment: Also, on the Rose Tree recommendation, the node contents can be a type alias, e.g. `type alias Folder = { name : String }`, which (I think) addresses your concern about access via pattern matching being too messy